# Xamarin Android how to update layout elements while running a subactivty

Tags: android, android-activity, xamarin

In the land of Android I am starting out. One thing that cannot seem to find is basic layman example how do this:

Main activity - press a button
Button calls a new activity
New activity gets user selection of data stores selection to Activity Preferences.
New activity finishes
Back to Main activity - refresh UI with text of selection from previous activity.

What I am running into that when the button click event run it calls the activity, but continues running the other functions. The updating of the text element runs immedidately after sub activity is called. I would like this to happen when the subactivity is finshed and returns control back the the main activity.

Or more to the point - how to have the view of the resuming activity update with changes.

```
buttonTask.Click += delegate {
    Intent TaskSet = new Intent ();
    TaskSet.SetClass (this, typeof(TaskSelection));
    this.StartActivity(TaskSet);
    TaskName.Text= settingsRFID.GetString("TaskName","");
};
```

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use [`startActivityForResult(Intent, int)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29) instead of `startActivity(Intent)`.

When you do this, your Activity will get a callback to [`onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult%28int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent%29) when the second Activity finishes.

Your second Activity should call [`setResult(int, Intent)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setResult%28int%29) to set up the `data` Intent that is passed back to the first Activity.

Your Activities might look something like this-

**MainActivity**:

```
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        buttonTask.Click += delegate {
            Intent TaskSet = new Intent ();
            TaskSet.SetClass (this, typeof(TaskSelection));
            this.StartActivityForResult(TaskSet, 123);
            TaskName.Text= settingsRFID.GetString("TaskName","");
        };
    }

    protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == 123)
        {
            if (resultCode == Result.Ok)
            {
                 data.GetStringExtra("myStringKey");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**TaskSelection**:

```
public class TaskSelection : Activity
{
    private void returnResults()
    {
        var resultData = new Intent();
        resultData.PutExtra("myStringKey", "value");
        SetResult(Result.Ok, resultData);
    }
}
```

For more information, see [Starting Activities and Getting Results](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities).

Comment: That is EXACTLY what I was looking for. The only tweak was to pass string to returnResults and then replaced "value" with the string. Thank you.